# how to add two different parent elements to a common child element in sass?

Tags: html, css, sass

is there a way to add two different parent elements to a single common child element?

both the next and prev contain a span element in their HTML structure.

```
.carousel-control-next,.carousel-control-prev{
       width:unset;
        span{
            background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='rgb(252,122,34)' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")!important;
        }


    }
```

This only applies to the next element " .carousel-control-next" but doesn't apply to the prev ".carousel-control-prev"?How to make it apply for both at once?

Comment: your code is correct. the issue is not there check other classes or html

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
.parent1, .parent2 {
  & .child {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Rendered CSS is:

```
.parent1 .child, .parent2 .child {
  color: red;
}
```

I think adding a class directly to the child regardless of the parent would be a better option:

```
.redChild {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct format for css:

```
.carousel-control-next span,.carousel-control-prev span{
background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='rgb(252,122,34)' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment,that will work but .carousel-control-next and .carousel-control-prev have a common width:unset;  so i didn't choose to use .carousel-control-next span,.carousel-control-prev span.